# NPN does not simulate in VHDL

Tags: switch-statement, vhdl

I coded the following code for a VHDL NPN switch but for some reason though the syntax is correct and it compiles fine, the output does not work on simulation.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
LIBRARY work;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity npn is port (
    p_In : in std_logic;
    p_Gate: in std_logic;
    p_Out : out std_logic     
);
end; 

architecture Simple of npn is 
begin
    process(p_In, p_Gate)
        variable control: std_Logic;
    begin
        case p_Gate is
            when '0' | 'L' =>
                p_Out <= '0';
            when '1' | 'H' =>
                p_Out <= p_In;
            when others =>
                p_Out <= '0';
        end case;
    end process;
end;
```

Ok, the problem is the simulation shows 0 transition regardless of the inputs I use in the p_In and p_Gate. What could be the problem?
It's a simple code and any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you include what exactly you're seeing that makes you think the output is wrong? Perhaps a screenshot of the simulation? Perhaps the transition that is failing?

Comment: Should this be a NPN transistor or a MOSFET?

Comment: Ok, the problem is the simulation shows 0 transition regardless of the inputs I use in the p_In and p_Gate. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please could you post your testbench?

Comment: Hi, I compiled and simulated without using testbench. I hope this does not present problems. Also my wifi is unstable so sorry for the slow responses.

Comment: If you have no testbench, then you must assign signal values in your simulator. Otherwise the inputs will just stay uninitialized ('U') and no transition will occur. Did you assigned any values in the simulator?

Comment: Yes, I did in every possible combination for p_In and p_Gate. Still no transition. What could be the issue?

Answer (score -5):

You should use `or` instead of `|`

```
case p_Gate is 
     when '0' or 'L' => p_Out <= '0'; 
     when '1' or 'H' => p_Out <= p_In; 
     when others => p_Out <= '0'; 
end case;
```

Comment: No you shouldn't use `or`. I'm afraid you're mistaken. `or` is the OR operator in VHDL; `|` is used for alternatives for case statements. `|` is the correct syntax; `or` doesn't even compile, because such an expression in a `case` statement needs to be a _simple expression_.